# ¿Cómo corregir el error failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system?

Tags: android-studio

Cuando ejecuto mi aplicación en Android Studio con el emulador me aparece en el logcat el siguiente error:

> failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system

¿Cómo puedo corregirlo?

Answer (score 1):

Es cuestion de asignarle permisos de escritura.
Cuanto estes corriendo tu emulador has lo siguiente.

Vas a la consola de comandos de windows, y localizas la ruta donde tienes instalado el SDK, estando en esa ruta haces esto.

```
D:\SDKWIN\cd platform-tools
D:\SDKWIN\platform-tools\adb shell
root@generic_x86:/ # mount -o rw,remount rootfs /
root@generic_x86:/ # chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard
root@generic_x86:/ #
```

por ultimo presionas exit para salir del shell del emulador e intenta de nuevo.